# Removing white spaces between unicode charcters

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I am trying to remove white spaces between characters  from my text file and writing to another text file.
This is my code

```
f = open("/home/user1/Desktop/evaluation/gold", "r")
f2 = open("gold1.txt","a")
string =f.read().split()
s=str(string)
string2 =  " ".join(s.split())

f2.write(str(string2) +"\n")
f.close()
f2.close()
```

These are the  words but it is not producing the result.

```
matsya k kuññuṅṅaḷa ̔e 
ora kkara 
vistr̥ti yila ̔uḷḷa 
naḻ saṟi kuḷa ttila 
vaḷara ttu ṁ
kuḷa ttinu 
cuṟṟu ṁ
plāsṟṟa ̔ik  c valaya ̔iṭṭa 
nra kkēāla ̔i yu ṁ
āma yu ṁ
kayaṟi 
matsya k kuññuṅṅaḷa ̔e 
tinnunna 
sāhacarya meāḻivā kkunnu 
ta viṭa 
piṇṇākka 
kappa 
bis  c kaṟṟa 
peāṭi ccata 
ennivaya ̔eākke yāṇa 
naḻ  c sa ṟi 
kuḷa ṅṅaḷila ̔e
```

The result expected is those words words with out space

```
matsyakkuññuṅṅaḷae 
orakkara 
vistr̥tiyila uḷḷa 
naḻsaṟikuḷattila 
vaḷarattuṁ
kuḷa ttinu 
cuṟṟu
```

Comment: What is the significance of the `f` file object ?

Comment: It is for reading text file

Comment: Is this Python 3? Why did you use `str()` on the *list* of words produced by `f.read().split()`?

Comment: yeah Python 3.2. For making the list to string

Comment: What result are you *expecting*? What output do you get instead? Please don't leave it to us to guess at what might be wrong here.

Comment: I see whitespace in your expected output. What are the criteria to keep the whitespace in a line?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to remove spaces *per line*, don't read the whole file in one go. Process the file line by line instead, and make sure to use the *empty* string to join your split result if you really wanted to remove all whitespace:

```
with open("/home/user1/Desktop/evaluation/gold", "r") as inf, \
        open("gold1.txt","a") as outf:
    for line in inf:
        line = ''.join(line.split())
        outf.write(line + "\n")
```

You made several mistakes: you read the whole file in one go, then split the file contents in one step with `f.read().split()`; that also removed all newlines. You then turned that *list* into a string again with `str()`, producing the Python representation of the list with contents as one string. You then replaced all spaces in that string with other spaces before writing it to the output file:

```
>>> sample = '''\
... matsya k kuññuṅṅaḷa ̔e 
... ora kkara
... '''
>>> sample
'matsya k kuññuṅṅaḷa ̔e \nora kkara\n'
>>> sample.split()
['matsya', 'k', 'kuññuṅṅaḷa', '̔e', 'ora', 'kkara']
>>> str(sample.split())
"['matsya', 'k', 'kuññuṅṅaḷa', '̔e', 'ora', 'kkara']"
>>> str(sample.split()).split()
["['matsya',", "'k',", "'kuññuṅṅaḷa',", "'̔e',", "'ora',", "'kkara']"]
>>> ' '.join(str(sample.split()).split())
"['matsya', 'k', 'kuññuṅṅaḷa', '̔e', 'ora', 'kkara']"
```

By looping over the file object you get separate lines instead, allowing you to preserve the newlines:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> for line in StringIO(sample):
...     line = ''.join(line.split())
...     print(line)
... 
matsyakkuññuṅṅaḷa̔e
orakkara
```

Comment: No it is not working.  Not producing the expected output

Comment: @Karun: you didn't show us the actual result you got. Perhaps you are using the wrong codec to open the file for example. But I cannot diagnose such problems unless you show us *what you actually got yourself*.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I understand. What is sample then

Comment: @Karun: what output do you get then?

Comment: ['keācci', 'yile', 'samara', 'tte', 'nēriṭṭa', 'pēāl', 's', 'sanvidhāna', 'ṁ', 'parājaya', 'māyir', 'unna', '̔uvenna', 'ārēāpa', 'ṇa', 'ttē', '̔āṭ', 'prati', 'karikka', '̔u', 'kayā', 'yirunnu', 'addēha', 'ṁ', '.', 'samara', 'kkār'

Comment: @Karun: my code cannot produce that list, not from the input file you provided. Are you sure that a) your input file still contains what you said it contains and b) you are running my code?

Comment: @Karun: also take into account we are **appending** to the outputfile, so any old text you appended before is still going to be there. Delete the file first or scroll to the end.

Comment: I am using a big text file. I can share it with you to see.

Comment: @Karun: the output you gave me doesn't match the sample in the question either; that text starts with `matsya k kuññuṅṅaḷa ̔e` but your output starts with `keācci yile samara tte`.

Comment: nelli nṟe 
viḷa kkālatta 
matsya k kuññuṅṅaḷa ̔e 
ora kkara 
vistr̥ti yila ̔uḷḷa 
naḻ saṟi kuḷa ttila 
vaḷara ttu ṁ
kuḷa ttinu

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't tell me anything. Perhaps you can use https://gist.github.com/ to produce an input file and the output you are getting now. You could even add your current code that produced the output file.

Comment: @Karun: a gist can contain more than one file.